# C++ operator delete override not always used

Tags: c++, new-operator, googletest, delete-operator

I have some C++ unit tests using google test. Threw together some code to override the new/delete operators to check for leaks in the unit tests. Having an issue though. Some of the google test new/deletes use my overridden methods, but some don't, so I get false errors in the tracking code -- sometimes seeing that memory was leaked even though it was really deleted and sometimes seeing that malloc returns

Here is my minimal new/delete overrides (just prints the addresses for manual inspection):

```
void * operator new(size_t size)
{
  void * addr = malloc(size);
  std::cout << "    tracking create: " << addr << "(size " << size << ")" << std::endl;
  return addr;
}
void * operator new[](size_t size)
{
  void * addr = malloc(size);
  std::cout << "    tracking create: " << addr << "(size " << size << ")" << std::endl;
  return addr;
}

void operator delete(void * addr) noexcept
{
  std::cout << "    tracking delete: " << addr << std::endl;
  free(addr);
}

void operator delete[](void * addr) noexcept
{
  std::cout << "    tracking delete: " << addr << std::endl;
  free(addr);
}
```

And here is the google test line that does NOT go through my overridden delete (gtest-port.h):

```
void reset(T* p = NULL) {
    if (p != ptr_) {
      if (IsTrue(sizeof(T) > 0)) {  // Makes sure T is a complete type.
        delete ptr_;
      }
      ptr_ = p;
    }
  }
```

When I break on the `delete ptr_` line in gdb, then step, it steps directly to the `ptr_ = p` line, so there isn't something else overriding that delete.

I'm building gtest as an archive file and linking it in when I build my unit tests. In case it matters: I'm on windows building with mingw using cygwin.

Here's a minimal example, 2 files min.cpp and minmain.cpp. Here's min.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

// Overload the new/delete operators to check for memory errors
void * operator new(size_t size)
{
  void * addr = malloc(size);
  std::cout << "    tracking create: " << addr << "(size " << size << ")" << std::endl;
  return addr;
}
void * operator new[](size_t size)
{
  void * addr = malloc(size);
  std::cout << "    tracking create: " << addr << "(size " << size << ")" << std::endl;
  return addr;
}

void operator delete(void * addr) noexcept
{
  std::cout << "    tracking delete: " << addr << std::endl;
  free(addr);
}

void operator delete[](void * addr) noexcept
{
  std::cout << "    tracking delete: " << addr << std::endl;
  free(addr);
}
```

minmain.cpp:

```
#include "gtest/gtest.h"

TEST(MinTest, MinimalTest)
{
  int test = 5;
  test++;
  test++;
  test++;
  ASSERT_EQ(test, 8); 
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  char* t = new char();
  t[0] = 't'; std::cout << "t is " << t[0] << std::endl;
  ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
  return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

compiled with:

```
/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++.exe -std=c++11 -D_USE_MATH_DEFINES -g -Wall -I../third_party/googletest-1.8.0/googletest/include -c min.cpp -o min.o
```

to create the min.o, then compile main and link all together with:

```
/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++.exe -std=c++11 -D_USE_MATH_DEFINES -g -Wall -I../third_party/googletest-1.8.0/googletest/include -o minmain minmain.cpp min.o ../third_party/googletest-1.8.0/googletest/make/gtest_main.a
```

Using version 1.8.0 of gtest, break at gtest-port.h:1145 to get to the `delete ptr_` line, then step.

Here is some sample output from running the example above (first few lines of output):

```
tracking create: 0x30e4c0(size 392)
tracking create: 0xa477e0(size 392)
tracking create: 0xa477e0(size 392)
tracking create: 0xa477e0(size 392)
tracking create: 0xa477e0(size 392)
tracking create: 0xa47b80(size 28)
tracking delete: 0xa47b80
```

The fact that I get tracked creates on the same address with no tracked deletes in between is a problem, because there were deletes in between allowing the same address to be allocated again, but those deletes did not go through my overridden delete operator.

Why does that `delete ptr_;` line in gtest not use my overridden delete function?

Comment: Because `ptr_` is `nullptr`?

Comment: Good thought, but no, otherwise I wouldn't be having the mismatch problems. I did just run it in gdb again and printed `ptr_` to make sure, it was not null

Comment: Consider having a [mcve] instead of making us to guess what kind of UB you have invoked somewhere else.

Comment: Absolutely, post  a [MCVE] .

Comment: And what's there in the header file? What's the "TEST" (macro?)?

Comment: Not a good idea to output to standard streams in global overloads of operators `new` and `delete`.   The buffers used by output streams can (and often do) use the overloaded operators.   The result can be infinitely recursive (`operator delete()` called which calls stream's operators which call `operator delete()`, etc).   Stepping through recursive functions with a debugger can be confusing (e.g. breaking at a line might only break on a deeply recursive call, rather than where you expect).

Comment: @user202729: the header file is part of the gtest library. It can be downloaded online, I don't think it would be constructive for me to post gtest's entire source.

Comment: @Peter yes, this is a good point, believe me I ran into the infinite recursion while doing this. But with how I printed, it is not causing this type of recursion, the program runs to completion

Comment: @user202729 The premise of the problem is about linking in an external library. I don't have a problem if I don't link in an external library, but I also don't have anything useful in that case. Should I just not ask questions that are complicated?

Comment: Hmmm... you can't reproduce it without including the library? Ok then, it may be a bug/feature/etc. with the library. You can keep the question in its current state, but (also) asking on the library's forum may be better.

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with google-test itself. I looked at the code in google-test that isn't doing what I expect (and posted that block of code in the question). More likely, there's something in how I'm linking it that causes it to not use my overridden function, which is why I posted on stack, hoping somebody can shine some light on what I'm misunderstanding about the linking/overriding.

Comment: If the problem comes with linking to an external library, the explanation may be that the library is compiled/linked and uses its own (e.g. the default for your implementation) operators `new` and `delete`.   While the standard requires that all compilation units in a program use the same versions of those functions (i.e. what you're doing is theoretically not a problem) some implementations are less smart in this regard when link libraries are used.   You might want to check if mingw is known to have such problems (I don't know offhand).

Comment: @Peter thanks for pointing me in that direction, I was able to find and verify that mingw does have a bug, and was able to find a workaround

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is a bug in MinGW:
[MinGW bug #634](https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/bugs/634/)

A work-around is to link the static version of libstdc++ instead of letting it link the dynamic library. Not the most ideal solution, but it's good enough for my unit tests and it allows me to override correctly.

I modified by compile/link command to the following to do this:

`/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++.exe -std=c++11 -D_USE_MATH_DEFINES -g -Wall -I../third_party/googletest-1.8.0/googletest/include -o minmain minmain.cpp min.o ../third_party/googletest-1.8.0/googletest/make/gtest_main.a /cygdrive/c/cygwin64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.4.0/libstdc++.a`

Mucho thanko to Peter for putting me down the right path to finding this.